# Is Heroku blocking my local git commands?

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So i've run a `heroku create` command on my django repo, and currently it is living on Heroku. What I didnt do prior was create my own local git repo. I run `git init`, create a `.gitignore` to filter out my pycharm ide files, all the fun stuff.

I go to run `git add .` to add everything to the initial commit. Odd...it returns:

`[1] 4270 killed     git add.`

So i run `git add .` again and get back this:

`fatal: Unable to create /Users/thefromanguard/thefromanguard/app/.git/index.lock': File exists.`

"Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue."

So I go and destroy the file, run it again; same error. Removed the whole repo, repeated the process, still got the same message.

Is Heroku running in the background where `ps` can't see it?

Comment: try removing the lock file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start over.

1. Destroy the heroku app
   `heroku apps:destroy --app YOURAPPNAME`
2. Remove the whole repo (I would even remove the directory)
3. Create new directory, copy files over (do NOT copy old git repo artifacts that may be left over, anything starting with `.git`)
4. Initialize your git repo, add files, and commit, then push upstream to your remote (like github, if you're using one) `git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial commit'` and optionally `git push origin master`
5. Then perform the `heroku create`

That should remove the conflict.